# Create unique list from vlookup or index/match

Tags: excel, vba

I love VBA but if it can be done with a fairly straight forward formula, that's better! (for the end user's sake)

Let's say I have the following data:

[image]

I'd like to create a formula I can fill down in column [D] that will lookup on "a" (this could also be a row rather than column) and return in consecutive rows (or columns) "red", "blue", "green" - that is consecutively return all unique values and then stop/error out or something...

Possible? Reasonable expectations?

***Bonus points for explaining how your formula works***

Comment: A pivot table can do this very easily.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good explanation of how to extract a list of distinct values with an array formula [here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/)

The basic formula is this

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:B$19, MATCH(0, COUNTIF(D$1:D1, B$2:B$19), 0)),"")
```

which would give you all of the different values in column B.

With some tweaking you can get

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:B$19, MATCH(0, COUNTIF(D$1:D1, IF(A$2:A$19=D$1,B$2:B$19,D$1)), 0)),"")
```

also as an array formula entered in D2 with "a" in D1 to select just the ones with "a" in column A.

It must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

[image]

The original formula works by

(1) Using COUNTIF to create an array where each element corresponds to a cell in the range B2:B19. If the string in the range B2:B19 is already in a cell above the current cell (initially D2), COUNTIF will put a 1 in the array: if not, it will put a zero.

(2) Using MATCH to find the position of the first zero (corresponding to the next string which hasn't been added to the list) in the array.

(3) Using INDEX to find the string in B2:B19 at that position.

I have chosen to modify it by adding a preliminary step

(0) If the corresponding letter in A2:A19 is "a", use B2:B19 as before - if not, use "a". "a" is already in D1, so it won't be added to the list in column D.

```
http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/
```

Comment: Not only does the formula not work, it also does not answer the question.  The question was: per value from column A, give the unique values in column B.

Comment: OK, thanks for the comment and when I get time I will improve the answer, but I've put in a screen shot and as far as I can see it does give @Methodician what they were asking for. I agree that a pivot table is good for this sort of problem, but I don't see how it work in this case when the data are non-numeric? If you can expand your comment into an answer, will give it +1.

Comment: BTW have changed one of the b's to "yellow" just to demonstrate that it's not included.

Comment: Yes @Mr Mascaro is right, it is very easy with a pivot table - just filter on column A and use column B as row labels. Will post it myself later if no-one else does.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question using a Pivot table:-

(1) Select Insert | Pivot Table from the ribbon. Select A1:19 as the range and D1 as the location, on the existing sheet.

(2) Drag Letter into the Filter box and Colour into the Row Labels box.

(3) Click on the filter symbol next to the table heading, Check Select Multiple Items and make sure only the check box next to "a" is selected.

You may wish to remove the 'Row Labels' Heading by clicking on Field Headers in the ribbon, and remove the Grand total by right-clicking on it and selecting 'Remove Grand Total'.

[image]